# Page object covers fixed navigationbar

Tags: html, css

Im creating a simple website where I want the navigation bar to always stay on the top of the page and I want it to always be visible.

I achieved this, but when scrolling past some elements, the navigationbar is covered up by said elements.

I have googled around for a bit, and everyone says to add "z-index: 1", but the navbar (which I did not make myself) uses z-index: 2 and -1, and if I change it to 1, the navbar just gets wonky. I'm probably just changing the z-index of the wrong object or something stupid, but I feel like I have tried everything here..

I may or may not have copy-pasted a lot :P

HTML:

```
<a relatively normal list> things in the list</a relatively normal list>
```

CSS:

```
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
position: relative;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 3px solid #a24fef;
font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul {
background: rgb(220, 220, 0);
background: rgba(220, 220, 0, 0);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
font-size: 0;
text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 18px 25px 12px 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -moz-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover:after {
  background: #a24fef;
}
```

**EDIT:**  Here is a jsfiddle with more code and it shows what happens. WARNING: THIS INCLUDES A GIVEAWAY WHICH PROMOTES STUFF. (couldn't figure out how to use an example giveaway so I used my friend's one.)

https://jsfiddle.net/vvqLLb1x/

Comment: Could add all of your code in codepen or something similar so we can see it in action.

Comment: this is not enough code to reproduce the issue!

Comment: Well the item thats causing the issue cannot really be included as it contains some private stuff, I was just hoping someone could give me some tips for things to try or something.. I'm sorry, I probably shouldn't've even posted this here..

Comment: Added more info now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by putting the whole thing in a div, then setting the div's z-index to a high number.

Answer (score 1):

There's really not enough code here to do much, but z-index is most likely what you will need to address to fix this issue.

In your code you have the following:

```
z-index: 2;
```

Think of a z-index of 0 as sea level. Whatever we stack above that line will have a positive z axis (thinking in 3 dimensions). When you are looking at a web page, you are looking down at it (helicopter view). The items with the highest z index will be visible and the items with a lower z-index (assuming they are on top of each other) will not be visible.

Somewhere on your page must be an element that has a higher z-index than the elements in your navbar. You can raise the z-index even higher than single digits.

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 18px 25px 12px 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 97;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -moz-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't be sure. Try this and let me know if it helps. If not, you will probably need to give us a little more code to look at. I hope this helps.

Edit: Try this:

```
html body .e-widget-preloader, html body iframe.e-embed-frame {
    z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

add that to your css file

Comment: Welp, now I know how z-index works.. Thanks :) The element in question has no z-index value though, and assigning one doesn't fix the issue :/

Comment: Added more info now :)

Comment: Ahhh....I see it now. Thanks for the added code. Give me a sec to look at this. We will figure it out.

Comment: Edit: Try this:

Look at the edit I added to my answer.    |     html body .e-widget-preloader, html body iframe.e-embed-frame {
    z-index: -1 !important;
}
add that to your css file

Comment: If it does work, please mark this as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but that seems to just remove the giveaway entirely..

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow: hidden;` to your css, i dont know for sure if this will work considering your lack of code in your question.

Comment: Nope, didn't work :( Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: Added more info now :)